# How can i make a dynamic plot with shiny.gosling?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

i am developing a web interface to visualize circos plots with shiny.gosling. my desire is to make dynamic filtering in order to make the user free to select a particular class to plot. i understood how to accomplish that with shiny but not in shiny.gosling. Can someone help me please?

here a toy script:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.gosling)
library(shiny.react)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
use_gosling()
library(GenomicRanges)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'visualizer',
  tabPanel(
    'Circos',
    use_gosling(),
    fluidRow(
      column(4, goslingOutput('gosling_plot')),
      column(1, br(), actionButton('download_pdf', 'PDF', icon = icon('cloud-arrow-down'))),
      column(5,
             br(),
             selectInput(
               inputId = 'classSelect', 
               label = 'Class:', 
               choices = unique(data_cnv_met$class)
             )
      )
    )
  ),
  theme = shinytheme('united'),
  use_gosling()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$classSelect, {
    selectedClass <- input$classSelect
    filtered_df <- data_cnv_met[data_cnv_met$class == selectedClass, ]
    data_gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(filtered_df, seqnames.field = 'chr', start.field = 'start', end.field = 'end', keep.extra.columns = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
    return(data_gr)
  })
  
  output$gosling_plot <- renderGosling({
    gosling(component_id = "gosling_plot", data())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$download_pdf, {
    export_pdf(component_id = "gosling_plot")
  })
  
}

track_coefs <- add_single_track(
  data = track_data_gr(data_gr, chromosomeField = 'seqnames',
                       genomicFields = c('start', 'end')
  ),
  mark = 'bar',
  x = visual_channel_x(
    field = 'start', type = 'genomic', axis = 'bottom'
  ),
  xe = visual_channel_x(
    field = 'end', type = 'genomic', axis = 'bottom'
  ),
  y = visual_channel_y(
    field = 'coef', type = 'quantitative', axis = 'none'
  ),
  color = 'red',
  tooltip = visual_channel_tooltips(
    visual_channel_tooltip(field = "start", type = "genomic",
                           alt = 'Start Position:'),
    visual_channel_tooltip(field = "end", type = "genomic",
                           alt = "End Position:"),
    visual_channel_tooltip(
      field = "coef",
      type = "quantitative",
      alt = "Coefficient Value:",
      format = "0.2"),
    visual_channel_tooltip(
      field = "class",
      type = "nominal",
      alt = "Class:",
      format = "0.2"),
    visual_channel_tooltip(
      field = 'gene',
      type = 'nominal',
      alt = 'Gene Name:'
    )
  ), 
  size = list(value = 2)
)

composed_view <- compose_view(
  layout = 'linear', #linear 
  tracks = track_coefs
)

arranged_view <- arrange_views(
  title = 'gosling_plot',
  subtitle = 'subtitle',
  views = composed_view,
  xDomain = list(
    chromosome = 'chr1'
  )
)

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```